# Simulating an interface by implicit typecast

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, facade

Suppose I have several classes `A1`, `A2`, `A3` whose data can be stored in the same POD data structure `D`. The classes differ with respect to how the data is managed, e.g., where dynamic data structures are being allocated. Yet semantically, they represent all the same type of data.

One of my `A?` classes is designed to be a wrapper around `D`'s. It can be constructed based on an existing `D` without copying it.

Now I want to implement read access to all `A?` classes in a unified way. I do not want to use virtual methods, nor do I want to templatize all code where `A?` classes are used.

Is the following a reasonable design?

Does this pattern have a name? (Facade?)

Are there any obvious pitfalls?

```
/* in practice, D is large or should not be copied for other reasons */
struct D { int * mymember; }

struct ACRef {
   ACRef (D const & d) : m_dataref (&d) { }
   /* operations for A-like classes */
   int getMyMember () const { return *(m_dataref->mymember); }
private:
   D const * m_dataref;
};

struct A1 {
   /* A1 stuff, manages m_data.mymember in a particular way */

   // implicit conversion to ACRef possible
   // kind of "is a" relationship: an A1 "is an" ACRef
   operator ACRef () { return ACRef {this->m_data}; }
private:
   D m_data;
};

struct A2 {
   explicit A2 (D & d) : m_data (&d) { }

   /* A2 stuff, manages m_data.mymember in a particular way */

   // implicit conversion to ACRef possible
   // kind of "is a" relationship: an A2 "is an" ACRef
   operator ACRef () { return ACRef {*(this->m_data)}; }
private:
   D * m_data;
};

/* A3 defined similar to A1 */

/* function that should operate on A?'s */
int printMyMember (ACRef a) {
   std::cout << a.getMyMember () << std::endl;
}

A1 a1;
A2 a2;
// ...
printMyMember (a1);
printMyMember (a2);
```

Comment: Why don't A* structs have an getMyMember() method, or getDStruct() instead?

Comment: Why not just use inheritance?

Comment: Should be fine from a 1st glance. What are your doubts in particular? Could you elaborate please? Or is your question, if this comprises the Facade pattern?

Comment: My doubts are caused from the often read advice not to use implicit type conversions. Second reason: I've never seen that approach anywhere.

Comment: If I use inheritance, A1, A2 and A3 have to inherit from ACRef. Yet then either they all inherit ACRef's D * const data member, or, if I put the A?'s D data member into ACRef, then I cannot build ACRefs from an existing D struct without copying it.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Giving A structs a getMyMember () member functions does not help me in implementing printMyMember. Which data type should it take if it is not a template?

Comment: @JohnB Perhaps make that requirement for `ACRef` clear in your question.

Comment: Now it should be clear, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

The only drawback I see with this approach is that you end up with multiple objects that implicitly share state. So e.g. passing an ACRef by value doesn't have the typical meaning. But as long as you only allow read access via `ACRef` it should not bee a big problem.
If the proxy types end up in a different thread than the original object, you have to be very carfull though.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything obviously wrong with your approach but wise people have told me to avoid implicit type conversions so it makes me a little nervous. Something smells about creating a new object every time you take advantage of the "is-a" relationship.

The more idiomatic way of representing an "is-a" relationship would be to use inheritance.

To accommodate your requirement on `ACRef` we could use the [Base-from-Member](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member) idiom:

```
struct D { int member; };

class ACRef {
  const D *data_ref;
 public:
  ACRef(const D &data) : data_ref(&data){}
  int getMember() const { return data_ref->member; }   
};

struct BaseA {
  D data;
  BaseA() : data({0}){}
};

class A1 : protected BaseA, public ACRef {
 public:
  A1() : ACRef(data){}
};

class A2 : protected BaseA, public ACRef {
 public:
  A2() : ACRef(data){}    
};

void printMyMember(const ACRef& a) {
  std::cout << a.getMember() << "\n";
}

int main() {
  A1 a1;
  printMyMember(a1);

  D d = {1};
  ACRef acref(d);
  printMyMember(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can rely on offsetof(m_data) being consistent (your example mixes full member and pointers)

In order to get the guaranteed behaviour you need a base class which defines the common behaviour.

```
class Abase{ protected D* m_data;...}
```

Only then will the cast be safe from A* to Abase* (imagine vtable getting added to support destructor, rtti) for some A

Comment: I do not think this is correct, as I do not (and the compiler will not allow me to) cast `A1*` to `ACRef *`, but rather `A1` to `ACRef`.